# JPA 2.0 Map two collections of the same type using one @JoinedTable

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Suppose I have the following entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
  private List<B> bList1;

  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID"))
  private List<B> bList2;

  // getters and setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B") 
public class B implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  //some other data
  //getters and setters
}
```

And the @JoinTable structure would be somthing like:

```
A_B (a_id, b_id, discriminator);
```

Is it possible using some annotation to specify the discriminator column, based on which bList1 and bList2 will be populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the code posted it is not possible because even when you could specify `@Where("discriminator='list1'")` and `@Where("discriminator='list2'")` on the collections to filter when retrieving, but hibernate still does not maintain the discriminator while insert/update.

you could try to make this work (i havent testet this):

```
@ManyToAny(metaColumn = @Column( name = "discriminator" ) )
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
    @MetaValue( value = "list1", targetEntity = B.class ) } )
private List<B> bList1;

@ManyToAny(metaColumn = @Column( name = "discriminator" ) )
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long", metaType = "string", metaValues = {
    @MetaValue( value = "list2", targetEntity = B.class ) } )
private List<B> bList2;
```

or you just create a class for the jointable which has a discriminator value and handle it in the properties of list1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Eventually I solved the problem by creating a separate entity for the JoinTable, as you suggested in the second part of your answer, but I'll try to test the first one also and let you know if this works. However, the major downside of the first option is using Hibernate-specific annotations...

Comment: I tried your solution. This sort of mapping assumes that the discriminator column is in the `B` entity. But I wanted to place it in the @JoinTable. Anyway, I don't think there is a better solution, so I'll accept this.